# Should breadcrumbs reload your current page?

Tags: web-app, breadcrumbs

Let's say i'm in the lowest level of my breadcrumbs. If i click on it (the current page i'm in):

- a) Should it reload the page?
- b) Do nothing.

Comment: I don't usually find a breadcrumb with an active link to the current page, just the pages that are the ancestors. As such, if you intend to provide it anyway, I would expect NOTHING happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

b)Do nothing
The purpose of breadcrumbs is addressing to users where they are and allow them to get back, the best way is to keep its behaviour and don't make it secondary menu.

*Home > Product > Item (text only)*

Comment: I disagree. If there's any data loaded on the page, you should be able to reload it with it's own menu item... Like a refresh button (but the web is moving away from F5 refreshes).